# Syntax Error React App, Issue with npm dependencies

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack

I have a website that I've had up for maybe a couple of years now, and I think it's starting to get outdated. I haven't touched it in a while, so I'm not exactly sure what is going on with it. I'm not exactly sure what the issue is, but it might have to do with my `webpack` version, or maybe my react version, I'm not really sure.

The issue started because I was trying to run `webpack --mode production` because I wanted to remake the `bundle.js` file, and when I would run this command, the file wouldn't create the `bundle.js`. Eventually I somehow came to the conclusion that there was something wrong with my `webpack` version, and so I updated it to the most recent version that was compatible with my dependencies which was version 4.46.0. I tried the command again, and this time it gives me this error:

```
[0] ./src/index.js 666 bytes {0} [built] [failed] [1 error]

ERROR in ./src/index.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (6:4)

  4 |
  5 | ReactDOM.render(
> 6 |     <App />,
    |     ^
  7 |     document.getElementById("root")
  8 | );
```

I tried reinstalling different versions of `babel-loader`, but the least bad error seems to be with the version 7.1.5. I also tried deleting my `node-modules` and then running `npm install`. Here is my `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "mywebsite",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --mode production",
    "set-dev-server": "webpack-dev-server --open --mode development",
    "start": "npm run build && npm run set-dev-server",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d dist",
    "publish-demo": "npm run build && npm run deploy"
  },
    "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+my/github/link"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "my/github/link/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "my/github/link",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.11",
    "gh-pages": "^1.2.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "image-webpack-loader": "^7.0.1",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "node-css": "^0.1.0",
    "react": "^16.14.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.14.0",
    "sass-loader": "^7.3.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.21.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.2.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.5.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.13.8",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.5",
    "css-loader": "^5.1.1",
    "node-sass": "^5.0.0",
    "schema-utils": "^3.0.0",
    "webpack": "^4.46.0"
  }
}
```

From what I found online the issue could also have to do with the `webpack.config.js`, but all of the issues I could find were from really old versions of `webpack` (2 or 3?), but anyways here is what I have in that file:

```
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");
const bundlePath = path.resolve(__dirname, "dist/");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const htmlWebpackPlugin = new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  template: path.join(__dirname, "dist/index.html"),
  filename: "index.html"
});

module.exports = {
  entry: path.join(__dirname, "src/index.js"),
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: { presets: ['env'] }
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader' ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(gif|png|jpe?g|svg)$/i,
        use: [
          'file-loader',
          {
            loader: 'image-webpack-loader',
            options: {
              bypassOnDebug: true, // webpack@1.x
              disable: true, // webpack@2.x and newer
            },
          },
        ],
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: { extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx'] },
  output: {
    publicPath: bundlePath,
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname,'dist/'),
    port: 3000,
    publicPath: "http://localhost:3000/"
  },
  plugins: [ new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(), htmlWebpackPlugin ]
};
```

Comment: I am not very sure I can help you fix it by giving some solutions.  Looks like the issue is happening because of babel

Comment: Do you think I should try different versions of babel?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using a jsx token `<>` while your file is named `index.js`. Try naming it as `index.jsx`

Comment: You can use jsx in a .js file too

Comment: I've never had this issue with needing to be called .jsx, but I will attempt it since maybe it has to do with something I downloaded?